# Compiling j2me using Ant

Tags: java, ant, java-me, compilation

I have created a J2ME project after referring to this article [J2MEUsingAntwithJ2ME](http://www.securitypronews.com/it/applicationdevelopment/spn-19-20030611J2MEUsingAntwithJ2ME.html). Now I am having problems in adding resources (such as images) and libraries (such as jar and zip files).
I have copied the resources in the `res` folder as shown in this article but when I extract the `.jar` file, it does not have any resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the sample:

```
<jar basedir="${build}/preverifiedobf"
     jarfile="${build}/bin/${program_name}.jar"
     manifest="bin/MANIFEST.MF">
  <fileset dir="${top}/${res}">
    <include name="${package_name}/*.png"/>
  </fileset>
</jar>
```

This will only include `*.png` files which are in `/res` folder. If you want to include more types, add more `<include>` lines or include `"${package_name}/**"`.

If you want to include the content of existing .jar files, you can [unjar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) them like this:

```
<mkdir dir="${build}/libs"/>
<unjar src="yourlibrary.jar" dest="${build}/libs" />
```

Then you can jar them up again:

```
<jar basedir="${build}/preverifiedobf"
     jarfile="${build}/bin/${program_name}.jar"
     manifest="bin/MANIFEST.MF">
  <fileset dir="${top}/${res}">
    <include name="${package_name}/*.png"/>
  </fileset>
  <fileset dir="${build}/libs">
    <include name="**/*"/>
  </fileset>
</jar>
```

The [Apache Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) contains a lot of examples for all the supported tags.

Comment: can i add libraries (jar or zip files) with this tag (<include>) ?

Comment: if you want to add jars or zips inside your jar, you surely can. if you want to add the contents of them, you will have to <unjar> them to some temporary build directory and add that one then.

Comment: can you tell more ?
and write a sample code for that artice ?

Comment: dear mihi, now i can add jars and zips directly but if i want add contents of them i have so problem !!! can you have some example from (securitypronews) article for me ?

Comment: I added an example of how to unjar a jar and jar it up again.

Comment: if i want add more jars i must unjar all them in "/libs" directory ?
and also what i must set in <include name="**/*"/> ?
(at the end i am so sorry for my stupid questions but i am beginer in ant and i have no more time for this project ... so thank you for your attention)

Comment: yes unjar all of them there.
You just set **/* (yes, exactly this, two stars followed by a slash and one star) if you want to extract all files from the jar. Otherwiese you can set something like "**/*.class" or "**/somedir/*.class" or "**/somedir/**/*" or something else. See the examples in http://ant.apache.org/manual/CoreTypes/fileset.html

Comment: this is my build file (http://rapidshare.com/files/246931651/build.xml.html) but it's not work and c:\lib.jar is not extracted in libs ? is wrong my build file ?

Comment: you have to put the unjar into a target (best into the same target that jars the stuff up afterwards). The jar fileset looks okay.

And please do not use R*pidsh*re for plain text files, there are hundreds of pastebin services for stuff like that...